# How can I display all the screen windows permanently at the bottom of VIM files?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I use 'screen' and vim together but instead of switching to screen mode to see what windows are open with

> CTRL + A, "

How can I make the status in vim at the bottom show all the screens windows that are open?

Comment: Why do that in vim when you can do that in screen itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want ? It set a window lists at terminal bottom.

[image]

Add the following line to your .screenrc, and restart screen.

> caption always "%{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{bw}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{wk}%?%+Lw %=%{mk}
>   %{yk}%D %{ck}%M%{wk} %{ck}%d %{gk}%c"